# Which design pattern to use to avoid duplicate data and sending same request again and again?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

There are two classes class A and class B, and both the classes are using same data and I am using HTTP request to get the data. Now since both the classes are using same data i can make use of inheritance and consume the data. But every time i create the instance of class A its sending request to server and same thing happens with class B. Instead of sending two request, Is there any design that I can send one request and when ever I create the object of class A or class B same data will be used without sending new request? Here is the sample code.

```
Class Parent {
   type data;
   requestService;

   constructor(){
      //retrieve data.
      this.data = this.getData();
   }

   getData(){
     //request server to get the data.
     requestService.getDataFromServer();
   }
}

Class A extends Parent{
   action(){
     //custom implementation for class A using data.   
   }
}

Class B extends Parent{
   action(){
     //custom implementation for class B using data.   
   }
}
```

Above both classes using same data but implementation changes for each class.Now i will create only two objects one of type A and another of type B.So now if i create object of A and B i will be requesting the server twice even though the response data will be same for both requests.So I want to send the request once and when ever i create object of type A and B i will be using the same data instead of sending request again. Is there any way that i can achieve this?

Comment: Having objects that send requests when you create / construct them smells like a bad design to begin with. You should stop explaining code and actually show some, how are the objects related, how do you construct them, how is a request made / data retrieved?

Comment: Please provide a code example that help understand the difference from class A to class B.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use observer pattern.When using observer pattern class A and B becomes your observer and your data(HTTP request) will become the Publisher.

**The observer pattern** - defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state,all of its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

**Subject interface** - Objects use this interface to register as observers and also to remove themselves as observers.

**Observer** - All potential observers needs to implement the observer interface.

**ConcreteSubject** - always implement the subject.In addition to register and remove methods,the concrete subject implements notifyobservers() methods that is used to update all the current observers whenever state changes.

**ConcreteObserver** - can be any class that implements the Observer interface.Each observer registers with a concrete subject to receive updates.

In your case  Subject class can be defined as follows

```
interface Parent{
void registerObserver();
void removeObserver();
notifyObserver();
}
```

Then your `Parent class` should implement Parent.`registerObserver` method should be able to register other class A and B or any other class that needs Parent Data.`removeObserver` should be able to remove these classes.

```
class ParentImpl implements Parent{
  void registerObserver(){...}
  void removeObserver(){....}
  void notifyObserver(){...}
  getData(){....}
}
```

Observer class will then have a simple class defined as follows

```
interface Observer{
  void update();
}
```

Lastly your class A and B will then implements Observer

```
class B implements Observer{
.......
}
```

Same as Class B or any new class that will need to use Parent Data.

```
class A implements Observer{
......
}
```